# Exclude "sold individually" products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I'm using this small php snippet on my functions.php in order to add a small text before my product quantity field on the WooCommerce single product page:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity', 'wp_echo_qty_front_add_cart' );
 
function wp_echo_qty_front_add_cart() {
    echo '<div class="qty">Número de asistentes: </div>'; 
}
```

Works as a charm, but I would like to exclude from this all the products that are using the WooCommerce native "Sold individually" option.

Is there anyway to do exclude them just by adding something to functions.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WC_Product::get_sold_individually()`, which indicates whether a product is sold individually.

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity() {
    global $product;
    
    // Is a WC product
    if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
        // NOT sold individually.
        if ( ! $product->get_sold_individually() ) {
            echo '<div class="qty">Número de asistentes: </div>';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity', 'action_woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity' );
```